# Spring Boot API - Issue with creating multiple entities in one Request Body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a request body with data for two different object(entities), for example.

- Task (with field as description) and
- Subtasks (with field as description)

One request body will have one task description and one or many subtask descriptions.

e.g.
{
"task":
{
"description": "test1"
},
"subtask":
{
"description": "test1"
}
}

I want to be able to create the task entity first, use the auto generated ID for the task and use it to create the subtasks(subtask entity has a field taskid)

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/add")
  public void add(@RequestBody NewTaskBody.TaskBody taskbody) {
      taskService.saveTask(taskbody.task);
      subTaskService.saveSubTask(taskbody.subtasks);
  }

private static class NewTaskBody {
      public static class TaskBody {
          public Task task;
          public SubTask subtasks;
      }
  }
```

**Task Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String description;
    
    //getters and setters

}
```

**SubTask Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subtasks")
public class SubTask {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private Long taskid;
    private String description;
    
    //getters and setters

}
```

**Task Service**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskService {
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;  //this is just a interface using JPA
    
    public List<Task> listAllTask() {
        return taskRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void saveTask(Task task) {   
        taskRepository.save(task);
    }

    public Task getTask(Long id) {
        return taskRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
}
```

**SubTask Service**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SubTaskService {
    @Autowired
    private SubTaskRepository subtaskRepository;  //this is just a interface using JPA

    public void saveSubTask(SubTask subtask) {   
        subtaskRepository.save(subtask);
    }

    public SubTask getSubTask(Long id) {
        return subtaskRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
}
```

**Question**
When I send the JSON using postman, the Task entity and row in underlyign dtabase is created but I get the below error (I suppose while processing subtasks)

```
"message": "Entity must not be null.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity must not be null.",
"path": "/add/"
```

Comment: please share the code for `NewTaskBody.TaskBody` and also the exception that is thrown in the console

Comment: private static class NewJobBody {
      public static class JobBody {
          public Job job;
          public JobItem jobitems;
      }
  }

The intention here was to wrap the received JSON into this class to it could be mapped to the two entities that I am interested in.

Comment: please edit the question and add the code as per SO guidelines

Comment: The code is already present in the code for controller class.

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here.

```
private static class NewTaskBody {
```

The object in your controller is parsed by some library that converts the `JSON` input into a request java object. In Spring by default this library is `jackson`. If it is private, the `jackson` would not be able to access this class in order to create the request object as you intend it to.

You should make it public

```
 public static class NewTaskBody {
```

You should also add `getters` and `setters` in that nested class, so that `jackson` could initialize the fields `task`, `subTasks` when needed.